# ~name in Joomla 3.8 path

Tags: joomla, joomla3.8

Recently Google has been sending me emails about 404 errors while crawling my Joomla site.

The URLs are not the primary URLs but seems to be a secondary setup.
So if the main site is(for example): www.mysite.com/index.php/interestingpage
The error comes from www.mysite.com/~alternativename/index.php/interestingpage.

~alternativename is a alternative product name we have used.
I don't recall setting it up but the 1st level works.
However as the crawler goes deeper into the site, the alternative path starts failing.

I have not changed my site recently but inn the last few days, I am getting 100s of errors from Google crawling.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a 301 redirect in your site's `.htaccess` to address this, if not, this issue may (slightly) hurt your search engine rankings.

The reason why Google is suddenly indexing all these pages may be because it found one of your old links somewhere.